# Client and server with different Locale - fallback mechanism

Tags: java, jboss

I have jboss server running with fr_CH locale and application client running with de_CH locale. I have two bundles - messages.properties(root) and messages_fr_CH.properties. It is strange, but while being on server side, ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundleLocation", new Locale("de","CH")) returns bundle for fr_CH locale instead of root bundle.

Only thing I could think of is that on server side Locale.getDefault() is "fr_CH", but if I get it right, due to concept of graceful degradation standard java fallback mechanism should not care about it...

any other thoughts what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this behaviour is because of default locale. Look at javadoc `ResourceBundle.getBundle`:

> getBundle uses the base name, the specified locale, and the default
>   locale (obtained from Locale.getDefault) to generate a sequence of
>   candidate bundle names. If the specified locale's language, country,
>   and variant are all empty strings, then the base name is the only
>   candidate bundle name. Otherwise, the following sequence is generated
>   from the attribute values of the specified locale (language1,
>   country1, and variant1) and of the default locale (language2,
>   country2, and variant2):

```
baseName + "_" + language1 + "_" + country1 + "_" + variant1
baseName + "_" + language1 + "_" + country1
baseName + "_" + language1
baseName + "_" + language2 + "_" + country2 + "_" + variant2
baseName + "_" + language2 + "_" + country2
baseName + "_" + language2
baseName
```

So your case is `baseName + "_" + language2 + "_" + country2`

Comment: thanks, probably this will teach me to read the javadoc better:)

Comment: 8) I've seen many of my colleagues (and myself!) get confused with default locales and this method.